# How do I check if the mouse left button is pressed all the time and not clicked only once?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

```
bool WasMouseLeftClick()
{
    return (previousState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && (currentState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released);
}
```

This code return one single click on the mouse left button.
But I want it to return when pressing the mouse left button without leaving the button and then moving the mouse around up,down,left,right.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward to me.

```
bool WasMouseLeftDown()
{
    return currentState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed;
}
```

This is simply a bool that returns true if the left mouse button is being held down in the current frame.

I think what you really want to do is when they move the mouse while the left mouse button is down so you simply need to check both conditions:

```
if (WasMouseMoved() && WasMouseLeftDown())
{
    // do something
}
```

I assume you already have code to check if the mouse moved (comparing the old position to the new position).

Comment: Trevor i have the mousemove i can do it with this variables i have:  previousState = currentState;
            currentState = Mouse.GetState();  but in the IF statemwnt that check if mouse move and leftdown how do i know if i rotate the terrain left right up down like i did with the keys ? with keys its simple W is UP S is DOWN but with the mouse how do i know when i moved the mouse left right up down inside the IF statement ?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question.  You're trying to decide based on the mouse delta whether it was UP, DOWN, LEFT, or RIGHT?  Between each frame you can have a delta like 10,10 or -25,5 which indicates how many pixels the mouse moved.  How do you want to respond to that?  For example if they move the mouse by 1 pixel in a single frame is that equivalent to if they moved the mouse by 100 pixels?  If this is your problem you need to try to figure that logic out and if you need help repost a question which specifically states what you want.

Comment: Trevor i checked it now played a battlefield game. I want that when i move the mouse without clicking/pressing any button or a key just moving the mouse around so me my self my point of view will move 360c degrees. The world/terrain will stay wont move its me that will move 360 like "look around" mode in first person games.

Comment: @DoronMuzar if your problem is no more what you're asking in this question, just add another question.